# Disable ipv6 support completely on debian squeeze 6.0.5

Tags: linux, debian, ipv6, debian-squeeze

I want to disable ipv6 support completely on debian squeeze 6.0.5. In many other posts I have seen setting the parameter `net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` should disable it.

I've set that parameter and rebooted, but `netstat -natp` shows me that the ntp deamon is still using ipv6:

```
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*      0    7983        3138/ntpd
```

Is there anything else I need to configure?

Comment: ntpd is probably being loaded before procps applies the sysctl (if it does at all). Though as a general rule you shouldn't be disabling IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem trying to get jabber to bind to the ipv4 address.  Found the the sysctl.conf didn't work but did have luck adding the kernel command line option ipv6.disable=1

Comment: Can you tell wich exact kernel version you are using?

Comment: 2.6.32-5 amd64, but that boot option should work with 2.6 and up.